# Gitlab CI/CD AWS S3 Upload Pipeline fails on dev branch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, nuxt.js, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab repository containing a landing page written in nuxtjs. The pipelines aims to build the project, generate static files then deploy them to aws s3 buckets. The following CI/CD file works perfectly on the main branch, but it fails on the development branch even tho the code is the same. The build stage works fine everytime, but the deploy_dev block throws the following errors:

`fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

or

`usage: aws s3 sync <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri> Error: Invalid argument type`

I already double checked everything:

- The env variables are correct and accessable
- AWS keys and the bucket url are correct

What am i doing wrong ? (beside the code duplication)

```
variables:
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  AWS_S3_URL: $AWS_S3_URL
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV
  AWS_S3_URL_DEV: $AWS_S3_URL_DEV

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - deploy_dev

build:
  image: node:16.13.0-alpine3.11
  stage: build
  only:
    - main
    - development
  before_script:
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  script:
    - yarn run build
    - yarn run generate
    - echo Build successful!
    - ls
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/

deploy_dev:
  image: python:latest
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - development
  script:
    - echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV
    - echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV
    - echo $AWS_S3_URL_DEV
    - pip3 install awscli
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV
    - aws s3 sync ./dist $AWS_S3_URL_DEV --delete #--acl public-read


deploy:
  image: python:latest
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - pip3 install awscli
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    - aws s3 sync ./dist $AWS_S3_URL --delete #--acl public-read
```

How do i fix the pipeline. Is this a bug or am i just missing something? Is there an easier way to just deploy static content to multiple buckets on branch push ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors here. First, the '$' in `- aws configure set aws_secret_access_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` is missing in both stages. Hence, your aws configuration is wrong.

Interestingly enough, it still works for the main branch. This is because aws cli first looks for credentials in environment variables, see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence). The user you use in the main branch probably only has access to the corresponding bucket, not to the bucket for the development branch. This is why you get the error messages.

To avoid such errors you could use AWS credentials as a predefined CI variable in gitlab in combination with [gitlab environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/).